# Disable pm2 log creation in node js

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, amazon-web-services, pm2

I am using aws ubuntu instance for my application and using node js to sync data from third party apis.

I have 6 node js scripts that calls every minute to sync data by making http request for many users.

For process management I am using PM2 module of node js.This pm2 creates logs for each running file ,this files size increasing tremendously and instance space occupied by log files.

Is there any way to disable pm2 log creation?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

We can user [pm2 application declaration](http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/application-declaration/) for our purpose and we can use:

> *Disabling logs*
> *You can pass `/dev/null` to `error_file` or `out_file` to disable logs saving.*

We can also set `max_memory_restart` parameter in **process.json** apps to set `autorestart` process on certain memory occupied by `memory.example` below for **process.json**:

```json
{
  "apps" : [{
      "script": "worker.js",
      "watch": true,
      "max_memory_restart": "50M",
      "error_file": "/dev/null"
  }]
}
```

Comment: dev/null where need to add, can you share an example please

Comment: pm2 stop <process_id> and
pm2 start <process_id> -o "/dev/null" -e "/dev/null"