# Node Project has not ecosystem.js file, So where I can put this script in my node js project?

Tags: javascript, node.js, pm2, pm2-logrotate

```
out_file: "/dev/null",
error_file: "/dev/null"
```

I want to disable **PM2 logs stroe in my local machine and on the server too**,

I tried to put this in `package.json` file after `"script : {}"` key,but it didn't work for me?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Disable pm2 log creation in node js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37745073/disable-pm2-log-creation-in-node-js)

Comment: I do not know where I can put that script, As I do not have ecosystem.js file in my node js project

Comment: When you run the start command on the server, that time add that as parameters.  `pm2 stop <process_id>` and `pm2 start <process_id> -o "/dev/null" -e "/dev/null"`

Comment: @MukeshSinghThakur Thank you! Your suggested solution is working for me

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.